# Extend myUser - create an Attribute

Tags: php, session, symfony1, session-cookies, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4. When I call any action in symfony for the first time, symfony creates a session automatically. Because of session fixation attacks, symfony creates a new session when I authenticate the user to true.

I need the old session_id()? Can I get it easy?

Or is there any way to extend the user session, for example:

```
class myUser extends sfBasicSecurityUser {
    public function OldSessionId() {
        $this->getUser()->setAttribute('old_id', session());
    }
}
```

But how does this run automatic, when symonfy is creating a session? Or how should look like the autoload.yml?

Thanks in advance!

Craphunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, however, when the user signs in, the pass through sfGuardAuth->executeSignin(). You can add to that action in the actions.class.php file to establish your session identifier.

It seems to me like you want to track something that the user did "before" they logged in. This would be a good place to serialize that, although there are plenty of methods to use to save that user's data.